# Localization class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, localization

I have created simple localization system for my app. What do you think, is there something "off"

Header:

```
#ifndef _LOCALIZATION_H_
#define _LOCALIZATION_H_

#include <string.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

#include "./tinyutf8.h"

class Localization
{
public:

    Localization(const std::string & lang, const std::string & defLang = "en", const std::string & defPath = "");
    ~Localization();


    utf8_string Localize(const std::string & key, bool * exist = nullptr);
    utf8_string Localize(const std::string & key, const std::string & group, bool * exist = nullptr);
    utf8_string Localize(const std::string & key, std::initializer_list<utf8_string> params, bool * exist = nullptr);
    utf8_string Localize(const std::string & key, const std::string & group, std::initializer_list<utf8_string> params, bool * exist = nullptr);

protected:

    typedef struct LocalString
    {
        utf8_string str;
        std::vector<size_t> replaceOffsetsRawStart;
        std::vector<size_t> replaceOffsetsRawEnd;
        std::vector<utf8_string> replaceNames;
        std::vector<utf8_string> replaceNameGroups;

    } LocalString;

    const std::string LANGUAGE;
    const std::string DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
    const std::string DEFAULT_PATH;


    std::unordered_map<std::string, LocalString> strs; //ordinary translation [key] = value
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, LocalString>> groups; //special translation [group][key] = value

    void LoadLocalization(const std::string & langID);
    LocalString ProcessSingleInput(const char * rawData);

    char * LoadFile(const std::string & path);

    utf8_string LocalizeWithReplace(const LocalString & input, std::vector<utf8_string> params);
};

#endif
```

Source:

```
#include "./Localization.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "./cJSON_JS.h"


//Limitation: translated string cannot contain {}
//These symbols are reserved for "translation replacement"
//eg: 
//active_label = Currently is active {active_id}
//active_id = something
//this will end in "Currently is active something"


Localization::Localization(const std::string & lang, const std::string & defLang, const std::string & defPath)
    : LANGUAGE(lang), DEFAULT_LANGUAGE(defLang), DEFAULT_PATH(defPath)
{
    this->LoadLocalization(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);

    if (LANGUAGE != DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)
    {
        this->LoadLocalization(LANGUAGE);
    }
}



Localization::~Localization()
{
}

void Localization::LoadLocalization(const std::string & langID)
{
    std::string path = DEFAULT_PATH;
    path += "gen_stringtable-";
    path += langID;
    path += ".js";

    char * str = this->LoadFile(path);

    if (cJSON *root = cJSON_Parse(str))
    {
        int keysCount = cJSON_GetArraySize(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < keysCount; i++)
        {
            cJSON *item = cJSON_GetArrayItem(root, i);

            if (item->valuestring == nullptr)
            {
                std::unordered_map<std::string, LocalString> tmpInner;

                int innerKeysCount = cJSON_GetArraySize(item);
                for (int j = 0; j < innerKeysCount; j++)
                {
                    cJSON *inner = cJSON_GetArrayItem(item, j);

                    Localization::LocalString str = this->ProcessSingleInput(inner->valuestring);

                    if (inner->string == nullptr)
                    {
                        tmpInner[std::to_string(j)] = str;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        tmpInner[inner->string] = str;
                    }
                }

                groups[item->string] = tmpInner;
            }
            else
            {
                strs[item->string] = this->ProcessSingleInput(item->valuestring);               
            }


            //printf("%s = %s\n", item->string, item->valuestring);
        }

        cJSON_Delete(root);
    }

    delete[] str;   
}

Localization::LocalString Localization::ProcessSingleInput(const char * rawData)
{
    const utf8_string EMPTY = utf8_string();

    LocalString str;
    str.str = rawData;

    size_t startIndexRaw = 0;
    size_t endIndexRaw = 0;

    size_t startIndex = str.str.find("{");
    while (startIndex != utf8_string::npos)
    {

        startIndexRaw = str.str.raw_find("{", startIndexRaw);
        endIndexRaw = str.str.raw_find("}", endIndexRaw);

        str.replaceOffsetsRawStart.push_back(startIndexRaw);
        str.replaceOffsetsRawEnd.push_back(endIndexRaw);


        size_t endIndex = str.str.find("}", startIndex);
        //str.replaceNames.push_back(str.str.substr(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1));

        utf8_string name = str.str.substr(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1);

        size_t groupIndex = name.find(":");
        if (groupIndex != utf8_string::npos)
        {
            str.replaceNameGroups.push_back(name.substr(0, groupIndex));
            str.replaceNames.push_back(name.substr(groupIndex + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            str.replaceNameGroups.push_back(EMPTY);
            str.replaceNames.push_back(name);
        }

        //str.replaceNameGroups.push_back("");
        //str.replaceNames.push_back(name);


        startIndex = str.str.find("{", startIndex + 1);

        startIndexRaw++; //offset by 1 - next search will start one character after "{"
        endIndexRaw++; //offset by 1 - next search will start one character after "}"
    }

    return str;
}

char * Localization::LoadFile(const std::string & path)
{
    FILE * f = nullptr;
    f = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");

    if (f == nullptr)
    {       
        return nullptr;
    }
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long tmpSize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char * origData = new char[tmpSize + 1];
    fread(origData, sizeof(char), tmpSize, f);
    origData[tmpSize] = 0;
    fclose(f);

    return origData;
}

utf8_string Localization::Localize(const std::string & key, bool * exist)
{
    return this->Localize(key, "", exist);
}

utf8_string Localization::Localize(const std::string & key, const std::string & group, bool * exist)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, LocalString>::const_iterator it;

    if (group.length() == 0)
    {
        it = this->strs.find(key);

        if (it == this->strs.end())
        {
            if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
            return key;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        auto jt = this->groups.find(group);
        if (jt == this->groups.end())
        {
            if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
            return key;
        }
        it = jt->second.find(key);

        if (it == jt->second.end())
        {
            if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
            return key;
        }
    }


    const Localization::LocalString & str = it->second;

    utf8_string tmp = str.str;

    if (str.replaceNames.size() != 0)
    {
        std::vector<utf8_string> t;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.replaceNames.size(); i++)
        {
            t.push_back(this->Localize(str.replaceNames[i].cpp_str(), str.replaceNameGroups[i].cpp_str()));
        }

        tmp = this->LocalizeWithReplace(str, t);
    }

    if (exist != nullptr) *exist = true;
    return tmp;
}

/// <summary>
/// localize string with replacement of "unknown" variables
/// eg:
/// key = "Hello {name} from {country} {xy}
/// country = "prison"
///
/// Call with 
/// Localize("key", {"Peter", "123"}) => Hello Peter from prison 123
/// -> replacement is used only for "variables", that are not found in other keys
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key"></param>
/// <param name="params"></param>
/// <param name="exist"></param>
utf8_string Localization::Localize(const std::string & key, std::initializer_list<utf8_string> params, bool * exist)
{   
    return this->Localize(key, "", params, exist);
}

/// <summary>
/// localize string with replacement of "unknown" variables
/// eg:
/// key = "Hello {name} from {country} {xy}
/// country = "prison"
///
/// Call with 
/// Localize("key", "", {"Peter", "123"}) => Hello Peter from prison 123
/// -> replacement is used only for "variables", that are not found in other keys
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key"></param>
/// <param name="group"></param>
/// <param name="params"></param>
/// <param name="exist"></param>
utf8_string Localization::Localize(const std::string & key, const std::string & group, std::initializer_list<utf8_string> params, bool * exist)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, LocalString>::const_iterator it;

    if (group.length() == 0)
    {
        it = this->strs.find(key);

        if (it == this->strs.end())
        {
            if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
            return key;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        auto jt = this->groups.find(group);
        if (jt == this->groups.end())
        {
            if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
            return key;
        }
        it = jt->second.find(key);

        if (it == jt->second.end())
        {
            if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
            return key;
        }
    }       


    const LocalString & str = it->second;   
    std::vector<utf8_string> t;

    int index = 0;
    for (const auto & elem : params)
    {       
        bool found = false;
        utf8_string s = this->Localize(str.replaceNames[index].cpp_str(), str.replaceNameGroups[index].cpp_str(), &found);
        if (found)
        {
            t.push_back(s);
        }
        else
        {
            t.push_back(elem);
        }
        index++;
    }
    for (size_t i = index; i < str.replaceNames.size(); i++)
    {
        t.push_back(this->Localize(str.replaceNames[i].cpp_str(), str.replaceNameGroups[i].cpp_str()));
    }


    if (exist != nullptr) *exist = true;
    return this->LocalizeWithReplace(str, t);
}

/// <summary>
/// Internal method - go over string and replace each {} with param at appropriate index
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input"></param>
/// <param name="params"></param>
utf8_string Localization::LocalizeWithReplace(const LocalString & input, std::vector<utf8_string> params)
{
    size_t count = std::min(params.size(), input.replaceOffsetsRawStart.size());

    utf8_string tmp = input.str;
    size_t i = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    for (const auto & elem : params)
    {
        size_t start = input.replaceOffsetsRawStart[i] + offset;
        size_t end = (input.replaceOffsetsRawEnd[i] + 1) + offset;

        size_t oldLengthRaw = tmp.size();
        tmp.raw_replace(start, end - start, elem);
        size_t newLengthRaw = tmp.size();

        offset += (newLengthRaw - oldLengthRaw);

        i++;

        if (i > count)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

It is build on top of the Tiny-UTF8 library, cJSON to load data from JSON file and uses C++11

Answer (score 2):

`localization.h` doesn't need `<string.h>`, but does need `<string>`.  In any case, prefer the C++ header `<cstring>` rather than the C compatibility header `<string.h>` - the former guarantees to declare identifiers in the `std` namespace.

Similarly, in the implementation file, prefer `<cstdlib>` to `<stdlib.h>`, and `<cstdio>` to `<stdio.h>` (but consider using C++ streams instead of C stdio; it's much easier to get right).  Yes, this does mean that you'll need to spell `std::size_t`, `std::` and others correctly.

Please don't name members in all-uppercase.  We reserve that shouting for macros, which should be used very sparingly, if at all.

Prefer pass-by-value for arguments that we store:

```
Localization::Localization(const std::string lang,
                           const std::string defLang,
                           const std::string defPath)
    : language{std::move(lang)},
      default_path{std::move(defPath)},
      strs{}, groups{}
```

But why are we even keeping a copy of default language?  We never use it after the constructor.

There's no need for `typedef struct LocalString` - in C++, a struct tag is automatically also the type name.  Just write `struct LocalString { ... };`.

The empty destructor adds no value and should simply be omitted.

There's no need to write `this->` when accessing members - we're writing C++, not Python.

Please use smart pointers to manage ownership, instead of requiring the caller of `LoadFile` to `delete[]` the returned value.

Think about error handling.  At present, if a localization file can't be read, we fail silently with no opportunity for the application to log a message.  This will make debugging more difficult.

We can reduce some tests like this one (which, though repeated, is strangely inconsistent with its use or not of braces):

```
        if (exist != nullptr) *exist = false;
```

Just test once whether `exist` is a null pointer, and point it write to a local variable instead:

```
bool exist_discard;
if (!exist) {
    exist = &exist_discard;
}
```

Simply write `1` in place of `sizeof (char)`, since `sizeof` measures in units of `char`.

Why does `LocalizeWithReplace()` pass `params` by value?  It doesn't need a copy, and should be passed as a const ref.

Comment: also if compiled using c++ 17 or higher it's probably good idea to use `std::string_view` instead of raw `char` pointers and some of `std::string`

Comment: @Sugar, the question body says C++11 - I'll edit its tags to match.